# Display related photo and $interpolateProvider in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a JSON data fetch from database.All data fields/value displayed except for the photo.Photo file names were saved in database and the actual file itself saved somewhere in other directory.In some templating engine I can display this easily

In twig

```
 {% for v in vps | sortbyfield('numbers')%}
 {% if v.numbers > 0 %}
    <tr>
     <td>{{ v.id }}</td>
     <td>{{ v.firstname }}</td>
     <td>{{ v.numbers }}</td>
     <td><img src="/img/{{v.photo}}" id="img-responsive"></td>
    </tr>
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

In angular file, I use the $interpolateProvider to customise angular mark up since I am mixing this in twig template.Again, angular js display data except for the photo data

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in names| orderBy:'-numbers' | limitTo:1">
   <td>//x.id//</td> 
   <td>//x.firstname//</td>
   <td>//x.numbers//</td>
   <td><img ng-src="/img/?"></td>//this part confused me
</tr>
```

angular js

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//';
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
    });

    app.controller('customersCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http) {
        //$http.get("http://localhost:8093/voters/voters_angular")
        $http.get("{{ path('vp_president') }}")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.names= JSON.parse(response);
        });
    }]);
    //console.log(names);
</script>
```

Some json data

```
[{"id":1,"firstname":"Alan Cayetano","numbers":6,"photo":"alanpeter.jpg"},{"id":2,"firstname":"Bong Marcos","numbers":0},{"id":3,"firstname":"I Dont Care","numbers":4},{"id":4,"firstname":"toto tata","numbers":0},{"id":5,"firstname":"titi terter","numbers":0},{"id":6,"firstname":"Ian Go","numbers":5}]
```

How to achieve this in angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this pretty easily with e.g.

```
<img ng-src="//srcFor(x)//" />
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.srcFor = function (person) {
  return '/img/' + person.photo;
};
```